# Phalcon routing

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

Hello and sorry for my English.

My site structure:

```
https://site.ru/category_1/.../category_N/post.html
```

routes.php:

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->notFound(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'error404',
));

$router->add(
    '/', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);

$router->add(
    '/{uri:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/\.]+}', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    )
);

$router->add(
    '/sitemapsyswrub7g5ox6mtz2tbplwiu6yduox6m.xml', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'sitemap'
    )
);

return $router;
```

1) First check the site.ru/sitemapsyswrub7g5ox6mtz2tbplwiu6yduox6m.xml

2) Next check posts.

Uri transfer to controller/action.

Controller look $uri and load post.

3) And next check main page.
site.ru/index.php, site.ru/index.html and site.ru/index.htm have redirect to site.ru in file htaccess
And it works.
But I have problem. If url:

```
site.ru/blabla_
```

then phalcon show error:

```
BlablaController handler class cannot be loaded

#0 [internal function]: Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher->_throwDispatchException('BlablaControlle...', 2)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#3 /home/srv/http/project/site.ru/public/index.php(23): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#4 {main}
```

If url:

```
site.ru/blabla_.
```

then ok, works error404.

Help to make the right routing for error404.

Answer (score 0):

url "sitemapsyswrub7g5ox6mtz2tbplwiu6yduox6m.xml" matched {uri:[a-zA-Z0-9-/.]+}

move uri:[a-zA-Z0-9-/.]+} in end file route rules

example

```
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->notFound(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'error404',
));

$router->add(
    '/sitemapsyswrub7g5ox6mtz2tbplwiu6yduox6m.xml', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'sitemap'
    )
);

$router->add(
    '/{uri:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/\.]+}', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
    )
);

$router->add(
    '/', array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);

return $router;
```